# trying to prove a theorem in $L_2$ (but has errors).

Tags: logic, propositional-calculus

First of all, The description of $L_2$ is as follows.

Primitive connective : $\land,\lnot$ 
$B \rightarrow C$ is $\lnot(B \land \lnot C)$ 
Axioms:
(A1) $B \rightarrow (B \land B)$ 
(A2) $(B \land C) \rightarrow B$ 
(A3) $(B \rightarrow C) \rightarrow (\lnot(C \land D) \rightarrow \lnot(D \land B))$

I have to prove that $\vdash_{L_2}B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow (B \land C))$ .Here are the rough sketch of my attempts.

**My first attempt:**

1. $(B \land C) \rightarrow B$
2. $B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)$
3. $B \rightarrow \lnot(C \land \lnot B)$
4. $B \rightarrow \lnot((C \land C) \land \lnot B)$
5. $B \rightarrow \lnot(C \land (C \rightarrow \lnot B))$
6. $B \rightarrow \lnot(C \land \lnot(C \land \lnot \lnot B))$
7. $B \rightarrow \lnot(C \land \lnot(C \land B))$
8. $B \rightarrow \lnot(C \land \lnot(B \land C))$
9. $B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow ((B \land C))$

Here, transforming from 4 to 5 was wrong.So I failed.

**My second attempt:**

1. $(B \land C) \rightarrow B$
2. $(C \rightarrow (B \land C)) \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)$
3. $ \lnot (C \rightarrow B) \rightarrow \lnot (C \rightarrow (B \land C))$
4. $ B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B) $
5. $ B \rightarrow ((C \land C) \rightarrow B) $
6. $ B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow (C \rightarrow B)) $
7. $ B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow \lnot \lnot(C \rightarrow B)) $
8. $ B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow \lnot \lnot(C \rightarrow (B \land C))) $
9. $ B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow (C \rightarrow (B \land C))) $
10. $ B \rightarrow ((C \land C) \rightarrow (B \land C)) $
11. $ B \rightarrow (C \rightarrow (B \land C)) $

Here , transforming from 7 to 8 was wrong.So I failed again.

I am out of ideas at this point.Can someone show me the right way to do it? (This is from exercise 1.55 of "Introduction to mathmatical logic" by elliot mendelson")

Comment: The proof is long and boring. See [Rosser](https://books.google.it/books?id=XH_1DAAAQBAJ&pg=PA66), page 66.

Comment: wait...Did you meant my approach was wrong and boring or rossers proof is long and boring?